# Microsoft Windows applications acting as X clients

Tags: windows, xorg

Well I know that using a X server (e.g Xming) installed on a Windows machine, I can see the graphical output of a remote machine on the Windows box.  This is easy when remote machine is built using X windowing system.  How it will work if both (local and remote) machines are Microsoft Windows machines?  Saying another way can I force my Windows application to display its window on a remote Windows machine while program actually running on a local Windows box?

Answer (score 2):

If it's XP then you can either use the builtin [remote desktop connection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remote_Desktop_Services) software, or use [vnc](http://www.realvnc.com).

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of VNC based implementations which allow per Window sharing (which will also work well under X). For example: http://shared-app-vnc.sourceforge.net/